# How to prevent that my Apollo Client error handler (onError, error link) is called twice for the same error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to implement a global error handling for a React application, which uses Apollo Client `3.4.8`.

I'm setting up the App and Apollo like this:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: cacheInstance,
  credentials: 'include',
  uri: configuration.API,
  typeDefs,
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Later on inside the `<App />` I add an `errorLink`:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    message.error('GraphqlError');
  }
  if (networkError) {
    message.error('NetworkError');
  }
});
client.setLink(from([errorLink, client.link]));
```

When the server responses with `502 Bad Gateway` the error handler gets called twice for the same error.

The first time from [`http/createHttpLink.ts`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/a3f8e99920bb6aa05d85207143e79eccb0023fb4/src/link/http/createHttpLink.ts#L201):

```
...
            observer.next(err.result);
          }
          observer.error(err);
        });

      return () => {
...
```

... and the second time from [`error/index.ts`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/a3f8e99920bb6aa05d85207143e79eccb0023fb4/src/link/error/index.ts#L77):

```
...
              return;
            }
            observer.error(networkError);
          },
          complete: () => {
...
```

Why is this happening that `onError` is called twice and how to prevent it?

I suspect that I set up the links wrongly?

---

It' seem like something is wrong with the link chain:

```
  console.log(client.link);
  client.setLink(from([errorLink, client.link]));
  console.log(client.link);
```

This results in:
[image: Log]

Comment: could you check what's in `client.link` before and after the call to `client.setLink`

Comment: @diedu You want to see which links are already in the chain right? `console.log(client.link)` doesn't contain that information. How to inspect the links? Maybe the real question is, how to inject a link before the terminating link, with a client retrieved by `useApolloClient()`.

Comment: yes, for the first console.log you should see something like and object or function and for the second after the setLink it should be an array with 2 elements, can you confirm that?

Comment: There is definitely something wrong. I've updated the question.

Comment: Not necessarily wrong. Maybe it doesn't work as I thought it works. I was concerned about the error link being added twice, but I guess we can't confirm that. could you try adding an HttpLink as they do in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#advanced-error-handling-with-apollo-link) `link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),` instead of passing the URI to the apollo client to avoid using `setLink`

Comment: This works, when I do `link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),` at creation of the Apollo Client. This is not the right place to do it for me, because the notification service is not initialized yet and also in different parts of the application I want to handle errors differently, so I kind of need to do it with `useApolloClient()`.

Comment: ok, try `client.setLink(from([errorLink, httpLink]))` I suspect that passing `client.link` is concatenating existing links

Comment: Where can I get the `httpLink` instance, which was defined within an application shell? It's another package, which doesn't export it.

Comment: `httpLink` is an [HttpLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/) you create with your uri `const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: configuration.API
  credential: 'include'
});`

Comment: This happens inside another package (we use lerna), so I cannot access it. Can I retrieve the instance via `useApolloClient()` somehow?

Comment: you certainly can retrieve the instance, but it seems you can't replace a link in the chain, which is one of your requirements (handling errors differently). I'd export the default links used to initially build the client from that other package to pass a new chain to `setLink`.

Comment: I agree. So the solution is that my "shell" package exports the HttpLink and the other packages compose a new link with it.

Comment: @diedu Thank you for taking the time and talking this through :)

Comment: no problem, I'll post an answer to summarize all this conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue here is that we can't replace a Link in the chain and when doing this:

`client.setLink(from([errorLink, client.link]));`

we could be adding multiple error handlers.

The solution is to apply again all the links we need + the new error handler we want to set

```
// create the HttpLink somewhere and make it available globally
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
  // Additional options
});

...

// somewhere where we need a different error handler
client.setLink(from([errorLink, httpLink]));
```